# Error intall php 8.1 on Debia 11 Bullseye

Tags: installation, debian, php-8.1

I cant install php8.1 on Debia 11 Bullseye

My linux:

[image]

Always appear this error:

```
root@flexsrv47:~# apt install php8.1
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências... Pronto
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto        
Alguns pacotes não puderam ser instalados. Isto pode significar que
você solicitou uma situação impossível ou, se você está usando a
distribuição instável, que alguns pacotes requeridos não foram
criados ainda ou foram retirados da "Incoming".
A informação a seguir pode ajudar a resolver a situação:

Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
 php8.1 : Depende: libapache2-mod-php8.1 mas não é instalável ou
                   php8.1-fpm mas não é instalável ou
                   php8.1-cgi mas não é instalável
E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.
```

I tried install the `libapache2-mod-php8.1` without success:

```
root@flexsrv47:~# apt install libapache2-mod-php8.1
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências... Pronto
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto        
Alguns pacotes não puderam ser instalados. Isto pode significar que
você solicitou uma situação impossível ou, se você está usando a
distribuição instável, que alguns pacotes requeridos não foram
criados ainda ou foram retirados da "Incoming".
A informação a seguir pode ajudar a resolver a situação:

Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
 libapache2-mod-php8.1 : Depende: php8.1-cli mas não será instalado
                         Depende: libpcre2-8-0 (>= 10.38) mas 10.36-2+deb11u1 está para ser instalado
E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.
```

Also tried install the `php8.1-cli` without success:

```
root@flexsrv47:~# apt install php8.1-cli
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências... Pronto
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto        
Alguns pacotes não puderam ser instalados. Isto pode significar que
você solicitou uma situação impossível ou, se você está usando a
distribuição instável, que alguns pacotes requeridos não foram
criados ainda ou foram retirados da "Incoming".
A informação a seguir pode ajudar a resolver a situação:

Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
 php8.1-cli : Depende: libpcre2-8-0 (>= 10.38) mas 10.36-2+deb11u1 está para ser instalado
E: Impossível corrigir problemas, você manteve (hold) pacotes quebrados.
```

And so i installed the lib `libprec2-dev` found on:
`http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pcre2/libpcre2-dev_10.36-2+deb11u1_amd64.deb`, installed with success, but still cant install php8.1

Can anyone help me please!